# Jquery variable to PHP Script

Tags: php, jquery

I am getting the values from a HTML Select like this.

Javascript:

```
        $("#Check").submit(function ()
        {
            alert($('[name="SCADA[]"]').val());
            return false;
        });
```

The jquery alert shows the array with the selected values from the HTML Seletec.

HTML / PHP

```
<form id="Check" action="Update.php" method="post">
   <select multiple="multiple" size="10" name="SCADA[]">
    <?php  
       $wec = $conn->prepare("SELECT SCADA FROM tblwec WHERE SCADA <> '' GROUP BY SCADA  ORDER BY SCADA ASC");
       $wec -> execute();
       while($row = $wec->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       echo '<option>'.$row['SCADA'].'</option>';}
     ?>
   </select>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit data</button>
</form>
```

I need to pass the values SCADA[] into the PHP Update.php! But When I do the $_POST method the variable is empty.

```
$SCADA = $_POST['SCADA[]'];
```

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Uhm, and where do you actually post the data ?

Comment: try `print_r($_POST['SCADA']);`

Comment: On the main HTML file the user choose SCADA numbers. Then I want to pass them to the UPDATE.php file.

Comment: That's great, but right now all you have is a form that is never submitted, so what's the plan ?

Comment: But when the user clicks on the submit data the data should be submitted? no?

Comment: @devwebapp — No. You're returning `false` from your submit event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate your select options you don't pass any value, so your post array is empty an it's normal...

If value is equal to label, maybe this snippet should resolve your problem.

```
<?php  
   $wec = $conn->prepare("SELECT SCADA FROM tblwec WHERE SCADA <> '' GROUP BY SCADA  ORDER BY SCADA ASC");
   $wec -> execute();
   while($row = $wec->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row['SCADA'].'">'.$row['SCADA'].'</option>';}
 ?>
```

Edit : You return false in your js function so data are not send... Remove this line and the form submission should work.

Edit 2 : You can access data with $_POST['SCADA'] variable, you don't need brackets.

Comment: but the array in the jquery alert is not empty! It has the values that the user seletec! Thank you

Comment: If there is no value attribute, then the text content of the element will be submitted instead.

Comment: If you want too see array content use 'var_dump' or 'print_r' function. When you 'echo' an array, you get only the 'Array' string.

Comment: Thank you! My mistake! So now if do print_r($_POST['SCADA']) I can see the array values and indexes. But if do $SCADA = $_POST['SCADA'] on the UpdateSCADA.php the $SCADA is empty. I need to pass the values of the array to the UpdateSCADA.php.

Comment: Maybe you should change form action to your UpdateSCADA.php